# Material UI Grid alignment

Tags: material-ui

How can I align items vertically in material UI?
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-wrn9x

Here I want put `Start` element and top, `Center` element at center and `End` element at bottom

I am looking for clearest and best solution

Answer (score 0):

If you using grid just do this :

```
     <Grid
        container
        direction="column"
        justify="center"
        alignItems="center"
        spacing={3}
        className={classes.container}
      >
```

you can use the interactive tool of MUI doc for play around and get the props you have to pass for create all the layout you need in the future.
https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#grid

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will make three grids - start, centre and end to appear in a column one after another. This layout will remain the same across all screen resolutions/breakpoints.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    border: '2px solid #969292',
  }
 
}));

export default function CenteredGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>Start</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>Center</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>End</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This code will generate a layout like below:
[image]